# SAS 4GL - multiple informats

Tags: sas, 4gl

Im learning 4Gl and I have little problem with informats:
I have file:

```
Imie;Nazwisko;Wiek;indeks;PESEL;Kierunek;Rok;Urodziny;Srednia;Frekwencja
Tomasz;Szan;23;114132;9134765445;Informatyka;5;5.32;99%;14.03.91
Karolina;Herl;21;134294;93543245;;3;4.57;92%;29.09.93
Damian;Kwak;24;189994;1234567890;Informatyka;5;3.50;80%;24.09.90
Ebenezer;Scrooge;AA;882741;78899609;Automatyka;4;3.72;34%;30.02.88
```

And 4GL code:

```
DATA projekt.project1;
length PESEL $ 11;
length nazwisko $ 15;
length kierunek $ 15;

INFILE 'c:\lasa_do_sasa\studenty.txt' DLM=';' MISSOVER DSD FIRSTOBS=2;
INPUT imie $ nazwisko $ wiek $ nr_indeksu PESEL $ kierunek $ rok srednia_ocen frekwencja PERCENT3. urodziny ddmmyy8. ;

RUN;
```

The problem is that: if I have xx%;date SAS won't read date. Im getting error:
 *Invalid data for urodziny*

anyone could help me? I tihnk Im doind something obvious...

Comment: The order in your input statement doesn't match your header line. And I have no idea what you mean by "have XX%;date SAS won't read date", can you elaborate. Though I think fixing the first part (input order) may help.

Comment: Also, I think you may have trouble convincing SAS that 30th February is a valid date.

Comment: 30 feb is part of my quest: I have to remove incorrect data, like date

Comment: Invalid dates like Feb 30th will end up as missing values when imported using date informats, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yeah, that was the point. Nevertheless: thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to use the `:` format modifier to stop SAS trying to read beyond the next delimiter after the % sign. You can also set the lengths of your other variables on the input statement this way:

```
data want;
infile cards4 dsd dlm = ';' firstobs = 2;
input imie $ nazwisko :$15. wiek $ indeks $ PESEL :$11. kierunek :$15. rok urodziny srednia :PERCENT3. frekwencja ddmmyy8. ;
format frekwencja ddmmyy8.;
cards4;
Imie;Nazwisko;Wiek;indeks;PESEL;Kierunek;Rok;Urodziny;Srednia;Frekwencja
Tomasz;Szan;23;114132;9134765445;Informatyka;5;5.32;99%;14.03.91
Karolina;Herl;21;134294;93543245;;3;4.57;92%;29.09.93
Damian;Kwak;24;189994;1234567890;Informatyka;5;3.50;80%;24.09.90
Ebenezer;Scrooge;AA;882741;78899609;Automatyka;4;3.72;34%;30.02.88
;;;;
run;
```